# Using GOMP_loop_static_start from libgomp

Tags: gcc, openmp

When the gcc compiler compiles the `#pragma omp for schedule(static)` it never calls the ligbomp function **GOMP_loop_static_start**, it use some assembler instructions to do the functionality of the `#pragma omp for schedule(static)`.

I'm implementing my own libgomp library and I want that when in the OpenMP application it calls `#pragma omp for static` the gcc compiler calls my implementation of the **GOMP_loop_static_start**.

Comment: You might look at the OSS runtime for Clang, which Intel contributed. It should implement the GOMP interface but is not encumbered by GPL virus, so you can do what you want with derivative works.

Answer (score 1):

It is practically not possible to get GCC to generate a call to `GOMP_loop_static_start` as a result of expansion of the `for` directive since a piece of code in the OpenMP expansion routines shortcuts the case of `schedule(static)`:

```
3123    static void
3124    expand_omp_for (struct omp_region *region)
3125    {
3126      struct omp_for_data fd;
3127    
3128      push_gimplify_context ();
3129    
3130      extract_omp_for_data (last_stmt (region->entry), &fd);
3131      region->sched_kind = fd.sched_kind;
3132    
3133      if (fd.sched_kind == OMP_CLAUSE_SCHEDULE_STATIC
3134          && !fd.have_ordered
3135          && region->cont
3136          && region->exit)
3137        {
3138          if (fd.chunk_size == NULL)
3139            expand_omp_for_static_nochunk (region, &fd);
3140          else
3141            expand_omp_for_static_chunk (region, &fd);
3142        }
3143      else
3144        {
3145          int fn_index = fd.sched_kind + fd.have_ordered * 4;
3146          int start_ix = BUILT_IN_GOMP_LOOP_STATIC_START + fn_index;
3147          int next_ix = BUILT_IN_GOMP_LOOP_STATIC_NEXT + fn_index;
3148          expand_omp_for_generic (region, &fd, start_ix, next_ix);
3149        }
3150    
3151      pop_gimplify_context (NULL);
3152    }
```

The code above comes from GCC 4.2.0, which was the first version to officially introduce OpenMP support. Things haven't changed much since then (only got much more complex with every newer version of the OpenMP standard). `extract_omp_for_data()` analyses the `for` directive and the associated `for` loop. It places the kind of loop schedule found in `fd.sched_kind`. If no `schedule` clause was provided, it uses the default for GCC `schedule(static)`. Neither `expand_omp_for_static_nochunk()` nor `expand_omp_for_static_chunk()` emits a call to `GOMP_loop_static_start`. Instead, they emit code that uses `omp_get_num_threads()` and `omp_get_thread_num()` to compute the iteration space for each thread:

```
#pragma omp for
for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
  ...
```

becomes:

```
<bb 2>:
i = 0;
steps.0 = steps;
D.1368 = __builtin_omp_get_num_threads ();
D.1369 = __builtin_omp_get_thread_num ();
q.1 = steps.0 / D.1368;
tt.2 = steps.0 % D.1368;
if (D.1369 < tt.2)
  goto <bb 3>;
else
  goto <bb 4>;

<bb 3>:
tt.2 = 0;
q.1 = q.1 + 1;

<bb 4>:
D.1372 = q.1 * D.1369;
D.1373 = D.1372 + tt.2;
D.1374 = D.1373 + q.1;
if (D.1373 >= D.1374)
  goto <bb 7>;
else
  goto <bb 5>;

<bb 5>:
i = D.1373;

<bb 6>:
...
i = i + 1;
if (i < D.1374)
  goto <bb 6>;
else
  goto <bb 7>;

<bb 7>:
__builtin_GOMP_barrier ();
```

Only `expand_omp_for_generic()` could emit code that calls `GOMP_loop_static_start`. For that to happen, the execution flow has to enter the `else` block, which happens either if the loop schedule is not static or if there is an `ordered` clause applied. In the former case, another `GOMP_loop_xxx_start()` will be called. In the latter case, `GOMP_loop_ordered_static_start()` will be called.

The only remaining option is for the region to not have a continuation (`OMP_CONTINUE`) or exit (`OMP_RETURN`) blocks. I see no way for that to happen since both blocks are always added by the code that lowers the OpenMP `for` directive. Later versions of the compiler removed the checks for exit blocks, but it is still not obvious to me, how the continuation block could get removed.